# Ubuntu 12.04 Wireless won't connect with gnome network manager or wicd

Tags: 12.04, wireless, network-manager, connection, wicd

I have an HP Pavilion Slimline s3100n and I cannot for the life of me get the wifi to connect and stay connected in any circumstances with network manager or wicd... I'm pulling my freaking hair out with this, and I can't get a dang thing down AT ALL... switching to wicd didn't work, putting my password in the connections editor didn't work... nothing at all is working... everything that everyone else is saying to me is chinese and I really just want my pc to work... please help... I will provide any information needed to help me with this. just instruct me on how to find that information. Don't pass this question by without helping me please... I'm so frustrated...

LSPCI -NN Information

```
    iceblueirish@iceblueirish-Michael's Desktop:~$ lspci -nn
00:00.0 RAM memory [0500]: NVIDIA Corporation C51 Host Bridge [10de:02f0] (rev a2)
00:00.1 RAM memory [0500]: NVIDIA Corporation C51 Memory Controller 0 [10de:02fa] (rev a2)
00:00.2 RAM memory [0500]: NVIDIA Corporation C51 Memory Controller 1 [10de:02fe] (rev a2)
00:00.3 RAM memory [0500]: NVIDIA Corporation C51 Memory Controller 5 [10de:02f8] (rev a2)
00:00.4 RAM memory [0500]: NVIDIA Corporation C51 Memory Controller 4 [10de:02f9] (rev a2)
00:00.5 RAM memory [0500]: NVIDIA Corporation C51 Host Bridge [10de:02ff] (rev a2)
00:00.6 RAM memory [0500]: NVIDIA Corporation C51 Memory Controller 3 [10de:027f] (rev a2)
00:00.7 RAM memory [0500]: NVIDIA Corporation C51 Memory Controller 2 [10de:027e] (rev a2)
00:04.0 PCI bridge [0604]: NVIDIA Corporation C51 PCI Express Bridge [10de:02fb] (rev a1)
00:05.0 VGA compatible controller [0300]: NVIDIA Corporation C51 [GeForce 6150 LE] [10de:0241] (rev a2)
00:09.0 RAM memory [0500]: NVIDIA Corporation MCP51 Host Bridge [10de:0270] (rev a2)
00:0a.0 ISA bridge [0601]: NVIDIA Corporation MCP51 LPC Bridge [10de:0260] (rev a3)
00:0a.1 SMBus [0c05]: NVIDIA Corporation MCP51 SMBus [10de:0264] (rev a3)
00:0a.2 RAM memory [0500]: NVIDIA Corporation MCP51 Memory Controller 0 [10de:0272] (rev a3)
00:0b.0 USB controller [0c03]: NVIDIA Corporation MCP51 USB Controller [10de:026d] (rev a3)
00:0b.1 USB controller [0c03]: NVIDIA Corporation MCP51 USB Controller [10de:026e] (rev a3)
00:0e.0 IDE interface [0101]: NVIDIA Corporation MCP51 Serial ATA Controller [10de:0266] (rev a1)
00:0f.0 IDE interface [0101]: NVIDIA Corporation MCP51 Serial ATA Controller [10de:0267] (rev a1)
00:10.0 PCI bridge [0604]: NVIDIA Corporation MCP51 PCI Bridge [10de:026f] (rev a2)
00:10.1 Audio device [0403]: NVIDIA Corporation MCP51 High Definition Audio [10de:026c] (rev a2)
00:14.0 Bridge [0680]: NVIDIA Corporation MCP51 Ethernet Controller [10de:0269] (rev a3)
00:18.0 Host bridge [0600]: Advanced Micro Devices [AMD] K8 [Athlon64/Opteron] HyperTransport Technology Configuration [1022:1100]
00:18.1 Host bridge [0600]: Advanced Micro Devices [AMD] K8 [Athlon64/Opteron] Address Map [1022:1101]
00:18.2 Host bridge [0600]: Advanced Micro Devices [AMD] K8 [Athlon64/Opteron] DRAM Controller [1022:1102]
00:18.3 Host bridge [0600]: Advanced Micro Devices [AMD] K8 [Athlon64/Opteron] Miscellaneous Control [1022:1103]
02:05.0 FireWire (IEEE 1394) [0c00]: LSI Corporation FW322/323 [11c1:5811] (rev 70)
02:09.0 Communication controller [0780]: Conexant Systems, Inc. HSF 56k Data/Fax Modem [14f1:2f20]
```

LSUSB INFORMATION

> Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
>   Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
>   Bus 001 Device 003: ID 0bc2:3300 Seagate RSS LLC 
>   Bus 001 Device 004: ID 058f:6377 Alcor Micro Corp. Multimedia Card Reader
>   Bus 001 Device 005: ID 15a9:0004 Gemtek WUBR-177G [Ralink RT2571W]
>   Bus 002 Device 002: ID 093a:2510 Pixart Imaging, Inc. Optical Mouse

Comment: Please run the terminal command lspci -nn and add your wireless card details to your question.

Comment: Sorry I am responding so late, I wasn't aware that someone had answered... also, the issue is just as persistent and annoying as my OP frustration... so I've updated the question... please reply soon, thanks.

Comment: Awesome! You have a rare wireless card that attaches through the USB bus. Please post: lsusb.

Comment: lol, rare huh? that sucks... I've edited the op to include lsusb thanks, please reply soon :) I've had to reboot my pc 12 times in the past 4 hours... oh I am running a slimline lol... compact case that's probably why they attached it to the back instead of putting it in the case.

Answer (score 2):

Your wireless device uses the driver rt73usb. Some drivers have trouble with mixed mode WPA and WPA2 networks. Please try setting your router to WPA2 only. Some drivers have trouble with 80211N; try setting your router to B and G speeds but not N. Finally, you might do:

```
gksudo gedit /etc/modprobe.d/rt73usb.conf
```

Add a single line:

```
options rt73usb nohwcrypt=Y
```

Proofread, save and close gedit. Reboot and give us your report.
Edit: gksudo for gedit, never sudo.

Comment: The editing of that file and reboot didn't work... I did save my edits. Does it have to be done in hand with the former that I need to wait until later to do?

Comment: Any of the steps are independent of the others. The goal is to find the step or steps that fix the issue. It make take some or all the steps.

Comment: Alright update: editing the file didn't work. We checked the modem settings and the router is already set up as wpa2 with a shared passphrase or something like that. On my pc the only options that are available besides wpa1 & Wap2 are none, wep 40/128 bit key (hex or ascii), wep 128 bit passphrase, leap, dynamic wep (802.1x), and wpa1 & wpa2 enterprise. Wep 128 bit passphrase didn't work even though I chose shared key instead of open on the authentication drop down and put the security passphrase for our router in. anything else I can try or another security type?

Comment: WPA2 with pre-shared key is fine. The only other suggestion I have is to update to 12.10 and see if the newer kernel version and driver helps. You can test it running the live CD.

Comment: I had this issue on 11.10 as well, hopefully updating helps...I just fear I'll run into way more issues because it's the newest version lol... let me try a live cd and get back to you... will the live cd actually factor the new kernel and driver when I test drive it?

Comment: The live CD runs ignoring your installed partition; it runs in RAM with its own kernel, drivers, etc. Like your device, the accompanying driver rt73usb is relatively rare and, I suspect, maintained only scantly.

Comment: I have to make a 12.10 cd real quick... but with my internet issues... it may actually take quite some time... let me get back with you guys, thanks for your time... I'll reply here again regardless of the results.

Comment: We look forward to your report and we'll be glad to help.